# How to make Phonegap's (Cordova) File API work like File API in normal browser

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, fileapi

Is there a way to make Phonegap's File API work just like same API works in browser?
I need same behavior as in browser: Tap on "Open file" button -> "Select File" dialog ->... -> Opening the file with FileReader Object.

Thank you!!!

**UPDATE:** I've found some solution. It opens File Dialog and it returns the name of the JS File Object. But when i pass that JS File Object to FileReader from PhoneGap - it doesn't open (onload listener never fires). What i do wrong?

Here's my Java:

```
package org.apache.cordova.example;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.ValueCallback;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaChromeClient;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;


public class cordovaExample extends DroidGap
{
private ValueCallback<Uri> mUploadMessage;
private final static int FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    this.appView.setWebChromeClient(new FileAttachmentChromeClient(this,     this.appView));
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage) return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;
    }
}

// openFileChooser is an overridable method in WebChromeClient which isn't
// included in the SDK's Android stub code
public class FileAttachmentChromeClient extends CordovaChromeClient {

    public FileAttachmentChromeClient(CordovaInterface ctx, CordovaWebView app) {
        super(ctx, app);

    }
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("*/*");
        cordovaExample.this.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose type of attachment"), FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
    }

}
}
```

And what i do with JavaScript:

```
 var SelectedFile;
 var FReader; 

 document.getElementById('fileBox').addEventListener('change', fileChosen);     


 function fileChosen(evnt) {
SelectedFile = evnt.target.files[0];      
     FReader = new FileReader(); 
     FReader.readAsDataURL(SelectedFile);
     FReader.onload = function(loadevnt){   ....   }  //never happens
}
```

Comment: First, set your onload listener before you call readAsDataUrl. Second you should register an onloadend listener so you know when the file is done being read. Third, what is NewPart? I think you want SelectedFile and what is SelectedFile? Is it a path to the file?

Comment: Sorry, it was SelectedFile (not NewPart). SelectedFile - it is JS [object File] from <input type="file" />. should I pass to FileReader only file path? How to get it? Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of SelectedFile?

Comment: If I alert it or log it into console it says: [Object File]. It has property "name" with file name and so on...

Comment: Right so readAsDataURL is exepecting a FileEntry object. Your SelectedFile should have a property called "fullPath". Without it, it won't know where to read the file from.

Comment: Ok, there is no property "fullPath". How to get it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem is most mobile browsers do not support the file dialog. IIRC iOS 6 is the first mobile browser to support this functionality. I did write some code in my [Corinthian](https://github.com/macdonst/corinthian) project, not under active development, that does monkey patch this functionality.

First you'd need to write an Android plugin to start an intent to provide the file dialog. I'm using OI File Manager.

```
package org.apache.cordova;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.LOG;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * This class exposes methods in DroidGap that can be called from JavaScript.
 */
public class App extends CordovaPlugin {

    /**
     * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
     *
     * @param action            The action to execute.
     * @param args              JSONArry of arguments for the plugin.
     * @param callbackContext   The callback context from which we were invoked.
     * @return                  A PluginResult object with a status and message.
     */
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        PluginResult.Status status = PluginResult.Status.OK;
        String result = "";

        try {
            if (action.equals("clearCache")) {
                this.clearCache();
            }
            else if (action.equals("show")) {
                // This gets called from JavaScript onCordovaReady to show the webview.
                // I recommend we change the name of the Message as spinner/stop is not
                // indicative of what this actually does (shows the webview).
                cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        webView.postMessage("spinner", "stop");
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (action.equals("loadUrl")) {
                this.loadUrl(args.getString(0), args.optJSONObject(1));
            }
            else if (action.equals("cancelLoadUrl")) {
                this.cancelLoadUrl();
            }
            else if (action.equals("clearHistory")) {
                this.clearHistory();
            }
            else if (action.equals("backHistory")) {
                this.backHistory();
            }
            else if (action.equals("overrideButton")) {
                this.overrideButton(args.getString(0), args.getBoolean(1));
            }
            else if (action.equals("overrideBackbutton")) {
                this.overrideBackbutton(args.getBoolean(0));
            }
            else if (action.equals("exitApp")) {
                this.exitApp();
            }
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(status, result));
            return true;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
            return false;
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // LOCAL METHODS
    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Clear the resource cache.
     */
    public void clearCache() {
        this.webView.clearCache(true);
    }

    /**
     * Load the url into the webview.
     *
     * @param url
     * @param props         Properties that can be passed in to the DroidGap activity (i.e. loadingDialog, wait, ...)
     * @throws JSONException
     */
    public void loadUrl(String url, JSONObject props) throws JSONException {
        LOG.d("App", "App.loadUrl("+url+","+props+")");
        int wait = 0;
        boolean openExternal = false;
        boolean clearHistory = false;

        // If there are properties, then set them on the Activity
        HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if (props != null) {
            JSONArray keys = props.names();
            for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i++) {
                String key = keys.getString(i);
                if (key.equals("wait")) {
                    wait = props.getInt(key);
                }
                else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("openexternal")) {
                    openExternal = props.getBoolean(key);
                }
                else if (key.equalsIgnoreCase("clearhistory")) {
                    clearHistory = props.getBoolean(key);
                }
                else {
                    Object value = props.get(key);
                    if (value == null) {

                    }
                    else if (value.getClass().equals(String.class)) {
                        params.put(key, (String)value);
                    }
                    else if (value.getClass().equals(Boolean.class)) {
                        params.put(key, (Boolean)value);
                    }
                    else if (value.getClass().equals(Integer.class)) {
                        params.put(key, (Integer)value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // If wait property, then delay loading

        if (wait > 0) {
            try {
                synchronized(this) {
                    this.wait(wait);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        this.webView.showWebPage(url, openExternal, clearHistory, params);
    }

    /**
     * Cancel loadUrl before it has been loaded (Only works on a CordovaInterface class)
     */
    @Deprecated
    public void cancelLoadUrl() {
        this.cordova.cancelLoadUrl();
    }

    /**
     * Clear page history for the app.
     */
    public void clearHistory() {
        this.webView.clearHistory();
    }

    /**
     * Go to previous page displayed.
     * This is the same as pressing the backbutton on Android device.
     */
    public void backHistory() {
        cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                webView.backHistory();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Override the default behavior of the Android back button.
     * If overridden, when the back button is pressed, the "backKeyDown" JavaScript event will be fired.
     *
     * @param override      T=override, F=cancel override
     */
    public void overrideBackbutton(boolean override) {
        LOG.i("App", "WARNING: Back Button Default Behaviour will be overridden.  The backbutton event will be fired!");
        webView.bindButton(override);
    }

    /**
     * Override the default behavior of the Android volume buttons.
     * If overridden, when the volume button is pressed, the "volume[up|down]button" JavaScript event will be fired.
     *
     * @param button        volumeup, volumedown
     * @param override      T=override, F=cancel override
     */
    public void overrideButton(String button, boolean override) {
        LOG.i("DroidGap", "WARNING: Volume Button Default Behaviour will be overridden.  The volume event will be fired!");
        webView.bindButton(button, override);
    }

    /**
     * Return whether the Android back button is overridden by the user.
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean isBackbuttonOverridden() {
        return webView.isBackButtonBound();
    }

    /**
     * Exit the Android application.
     */
    public void exitApp() {
        this.webView.postMessage("exit", null);
    }

}

package com.simonmacdonald.corinthian;

import org.apache.cordova.api.Plugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;

public class FileDialog extends Plugin {
    private static final int PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE = 8974;
    private static final int PICK_DIRECTORY_RESULT_CODE = 8975;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "FileDialog";
    public String callbackId;

    /**
     * Executes the request and returns PluginResult.
     *
     * @param action        The action to execute.
     * @param args          JSONArry of arguments for the plugin.
     * @param callbackId    The callback id used when calling back into JavaScript.
     * @return              A PluginResult object with a status and message.
     */
    @Override
    public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        this.callbackId = callbackId;

        JSONObject options = args.optJSONObject(0);

        if (action.equals("pickFile")) {
            showDialog(options, PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
        } else if (action.equals("pickFolder")) {
            showDialog(options, PICK_DIRECTORY_RESULT_CODE);
        }
        else {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        }
        PluginResult r = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT);
        r.setKeepCallback(true);
        return r;
    }

    private void showDialog(JSONObject options, int type) {
        Intent intent;
        if (type == PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE) {
            intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_FILE");
        } else {
            intent = new Intent("org.openintents.action.PICK_DIRECTORY");
        }
        if (options != null) {
            String title = options.optString("title");
            if (title != null) {
                intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.TITLE", title);
            }
            String button = options.optString("button");
            if (button != null) {
                intent.putExtra("org.openintents.extra.BUTTON_TEXT", button);
            }
        }
        //intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(new File("/")));
        try {
            this.cordova.startActivityForResult((Plugin)this,intent,PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            showDownloadDialog();
        }
    }

    private void showDownloadDialog() {
        final Context context = this.cordova.getContext();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dialog.setTitle("Install File Manager?");
                dialog.setMessage("This requires the free OI File Manager app. Would you like to install it now?");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int i) {
                        dlg.dismiss();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:org.openintents.filemanager")
                        );
                        try {
                            context.startActivity(intent);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
//                          We don't have the market app installed, so download it directly.
                            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            in.setData(Uri.parse("http://openintents.googlecode.com/files/FileManager-1.2.apk"));
                            context.startActivity(in);

                        }

                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int i) {
                        dlg.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        };
        this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      //super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
      //Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Data is " + data.getData().toString());
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "we are in on activity result");
      switch (reqCode) {
      case PICK_FILE_RESULT_CODE:
      case PICK_DIRECTORY_RESULT_CODE: {
          if (resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK && data!=null && data.getData()!=null) {
              String filePath = "file://" + data.getData().getPath();
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "The data is = " + filePath);
              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Calling succes with callback id = " + this.callbackId);
              this.success(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, filePath), this.callbackId);
          }
          break;
      }
  }
    }
}
```

Then you'd need to write your JavaScript interface:

```
FileDialog: {
    pickFile: function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
        var win = typeof successCallback !== 'function' ? null : function(f) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(f, function(fileEntry) {
                successCallback(fileEntry);
            }, fail);
        };
        cordova.exec(win, errorCallback, "FileDialog", "pickFile", [options]);
    },
    pickFolder: function(successCallback, errorCallback, options) {
        var win = typeof successCallback !== 'function' ? null : function(d) {
            window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(d, function(dirEntry) {
                successCallback(dirEntry);
            }, fail);
        };
        cordova.exec(win, errorCallback, "FileDialog", "pickFolder", [options]);
    },
    patch: function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
           if (inputs[i].getAttribute('type') == 'file'){
               var me = inputs[i];
               inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                   corinthian.FileDialog.pickFile(function(fileEntry) {
                       me.value = fileEntry.fullPath;
                   });
               });
           }
        }
    }
}
```

and finally monkey patch by calling FileDialog.patch(); once you have received the deviceready event in PhoneGap.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, Simon for your answer! But so much of code... I tried to implement some solution I had found in the Web: it opens File dialog, but FileReader doesn't work. I've updated my question with some code that I have now. Maybe you can help me to improve it? Thank you!