# Open/save client-side data in a client-side file in Cordova/PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

I know I could potentially use the [Cordova File plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-file), but that seems to have multiple, platform-specific quirks (such as different directory structures) due to its low-level nature.

Today I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28647235/897968) that shows how to open a desktop browser's Save Dialog for the user to select where they want to save blob data, but it was [[image]dart](/questions/tagged/dart) code so I converted the idea to plain JavaScript:

```
function onSaveButtonClick() {
    var blob = new Blob(['abcd'], {type: 'text/plain'}),
        blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob),
        a = document.createElement('a');

    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(a);
    a.href = blobUrl;
    a.download = "file.name";
    a.click();
    a.innerHTML = blobUrl;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(blobUrl);
    }, 1000);
}
```

[CodePen here](https://s.codepen.io/friendfx/debug/obKdbZ)

(Also note that the `download` attribute of the `<a>` is [not supported by IE, but Edge](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/adownloadattribute) and in addition to that, IE seems to block the `a.click()` call.)

In the code above, setting the `innerHTML` is only for debugging purposes and for production use, you may want to set `a.style.display = 'none'` to hide the anchor altogether. I am also aware that the `revokeObjectURL` call in a timeout is a bit of a code smell, but it seems to work in desktop Chrome and Firefox.

Now the question is: **How can I achieve the same in a Cordova app**? I mean, letting the user choose the file save location via a stock Save As dialog so I don't have to add platform-specific code to my app? Running this code in a Cordova app on Android just displays the anchor but doesn't ask the user to save the file - even clicking the link (before or after the timeout) manually doesn't show it.

### Update:

There is a related question here:

[How to make Phonegap's (Cordova) File API work like File API in normal browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754797/how-to-make-phonegaps-cordova-file-api-work-like-file-api-in-normal-browser)

The only answer requires the user to install a separate (though free) app and is therefore a no-go as I'd like my app to be self-contained.

Comment: it would depend on the android version, and if "browser" supported `a[download]`,  `new Blob` and `window.URL`. i have a download lib that has some fallback methods that might work for you: https://github.com/rndme/download ... with some noted limitations, it can download files in rather old browsers.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks for your lib, I tested it on Android 4.4 but it doesn't work either - I can see an `<a>` element appear temporarily, but no download/save dialog is started.

Comment: sorry it didn't help. i guess you have to bite the bullet and do the file system thing...

Comment: You can checkout [this](https://github.com/mikethedj4/Android-SaveFile-BinaryString/) Git Repo I made for PhoneGap Build - https://github.com/mikethedj4/Android-SaveFile-BinaryString/ ( Thanks to [@Whebcraft](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5112092/whebcraft) for the tip :) )

Answer (score 2):

```
   // Lets save a sample json data....

   function SaveData(fileName, Data) {
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getFile(fileName, {
        create: true,
        exclusive: false
    }, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.onwriteend = function() {
                alert("Data Saved");
            };
            writer.write(JSON.stringify(Data)); // if data type is not json use writer.write(Data);
        }, onError);
    }, onError);
}, onError);
   }

   function onError() {
alert("Error");
   }

   // function to create a directory if necessary
   function CreateDirectory(DirName) {
       window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory(DirName, {
        create: true
    }, function gotDir(dirEntry) {});
}, function fail() {});
   }


   // Create Directory
   CreateDirectory("My Folder");

   var fileName = 'SavedFile.json'; // or file name and path e.g My Folder/SavedFile.json

   // json data
   var Data = '{ "id": "5001", "type": "None" },{ "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },{ "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" }';

   // Save Data
   SaveData(fileName, Data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Cordova file transfer plugin to download files https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

```
  function downloadFILE(filename, url){
   var ft = new FileTransfer();
var uri = encodeURI(url);

// /Documents/ folder in the users sdcard or phone storage if sdcard is not available
var downloadPath = fileSystem.root.fullPath + "/Documents/"+filename;

ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
        var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
    document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = perc;
    } else {
        if($('#status').text() == "") {
    document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = "Loading....";
        } else {
    document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = ".";
        }
    }
};

ft.download(uri, downloadPath, 
function(entry) {
    document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML = "Download Complete! File Saved To" +entry.fullPath;
}, 
function(error) {
    alert('Crap something went wrong...');  
});
     }
```

Call with

```
 downloadFILE('npm-logo.svg', 'https://www.npmjs.com/static/images/npm-logo.svg');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer which is a nice example for the FileTransfer plugin. Regarding my question though, there are two problems with it: firstly it doesn't ask the user for where to save the file and secondly it requires the file to be downloaded from a server (I specifically asked for client-side data to be saved). As an aside, where is the `fileSystem` object defined?

Comment: ok I understand you better. Lets use this example, lets say we generated a simple client side data and we want to save that data on the users device in your custom directory (allowing the user to select a directory I really dont have an idea how to do that). see the full code below ....

Answer (score 0):

Mobile OSes are generally designed to hide their file system from the user. Downloaded files goe to OS/App-specific "Downloads" folder without the user being able to choose. Also OSes mostly do not come with a built in file-browser to randomly pick / select files to open. The Downloads-folder however is usually somehow reachable (e.g using the downloads shortcut) and hence those files can be openened by the user. I know this is not a solution, but may shed some light on why there probably does not exist a real solution for your question that satisfies all of your needs.